# .htaccess redirect everything to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect my pages from **mydomain.com/everything** to **everything.mydomain.com**, is it possible?

Something like this but with any word

```
#if not already blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for blog/, go to blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.website.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ http://$1.example.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

You can change the expression to match anything if you like, but that gives you an idea at least.

Comment: it works, but it's showing content of http://example.com(it should show content of http://example.com/anything)